# Ｗhat does it mean by integrity constraint violated - parent key not found in SQLplus

Tags: sql, sqlplus

**Here is my code**
**Can someone take a look. Thanks!**

```
//table
CREATE TABLE LINE (
REQ_NUM NUMBER (38,0) NOT NULL,
LIN_NUM NUMBER (38,0),
LIN_HOURS NUMBER (4,2) NOT NULL,
LINE_PRICE NUMBER (6,2) NOT NULL,
SVC_NUM NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(REQ_NUM,LIN_NUM),
FOREIGN KEY (SVC_NUM) REFERENCES SERVICE
);
```

**The bottom three data can be inserted but not the ones them**
//data

```
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES (500, 1, 35, 0.5, 45);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(500,2,20,1.5, 150);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(600, 1, 35, 0.5, 50);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(700, 1, 15, 10, 750);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(800, 1, 30, 48, 7000);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(900, 1, 25, 6, 450);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(1000, 1, 20, 1.5, 125);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(1100,1, 35, 0.5, 45);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(1100, 3, 20, 2 ,150);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(1200, 1, 30, 8, 250);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(1300, 1, 35, 0.75, 50);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(600, 2, 40, 0.5, 25);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(1100, 2, 40, 0.5, 25);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES(1400, 1, 40, 1, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem statement

Integrity constraint violation is the event when a command attempts to perform a an `insert` or `update` on a child `table` referencing to a nonexistent record in the parent `table`, or, when a command attempts to perform a `delete` or an `update` on the parent `table`, removing/changing a `primary key` that was referenced by a child `table`.

## Examples

In these examples I will have an imaginary table called `PET` and another one called `OWNER`, `OWNER` being referenced by `PET`, `OWNER_ID` being the `primary key` in the `OWNER` `table` and the `foreign key` in the `PET` `table`.

### Example 1

Let's suppose that there is an `OWNER` with `OWNER_ID` being 1. Let's suppose further that there is no `PET` with `OWNER_ID` being 1. In this case you can safely `update` `OWNER`.`OWNER_ID` or even `delete` the record where `OWNER_ID` is 1, assuming that there are no further references on `OWNER`.

### Example 2

Let's suppose that there is an `OWNER` with `OWNER_ID` being 2. Let's suppose further that there is at least a `PET` record whose `OWNER_ID` is 2 as well, referencing this particular `OWNER` record. You cannot remove the `OWNER` whose `OWNER_ID` is 2, because that would result in integrity constraint violation due to the fact that it's being referenced by `PET`. So, you either remove the referencing `PET` first or change its `OWNER_ID` to something that would reference an actual `OWNER` after the `delete` is performed. Similarly, you cannot `update` the `OWNER_ID` of the `OWNER` whose `OWNER_ID` is 2 for the same reason.

### Example 3

Let's suppose there is an `OWNER` with `OWNER_ID` being 3 and a `PET` whose `OWNER_ID` is 3 as well. If we update `PET.OWNER_ID` to 4, then it will succeed if and only if there exists an `OWNER` whose `OWNER_ID` is 4. Otherwise it will violate integrity constraints and fail.

### Example 4

Let's suppose that we attempt to insert a `PET` whose `OWNER_ID` is 5. It will succeed if and only if an `OWNER` with `OWNER_ID` being 5 exists. Otherwise it will fail due to integrity constraint violation.

## Summary

Since you try to perform an `insert` on a child `table`, your problem is equivalent to Example 4, that is, you attempt to `insert` a record into a child `table`, referencing the parent `table` with a value that does not exist in the parent `table` as `primary key`.

So, you will either need to remove the insertions that attempt to create orphan records, or do an `insert`-`select`, like

```
INSERT INTO LINE(REQ_NUM, LIN_NUM, LIN_HOURS, LINE_PRICE, SVC_NUM)
SELECT 1300, 1, 35, 0.75, SERVICE.SVC_NUM
FROM SERVICE
WHERE SERVICE.SVC_NUM = 50;
```

or to `insert` the missing records into `SERVICE` first, or remove the orphan insertions from your script.